# Node label in vis.js network failing to update

Tags: javascript, vis.js

I need to be able to toggle the visibility of node labels in a vis.js network. I'm trying to achieve this by calling the update function on the nodes of the network. My nodes are defined as a vis.DataSet which I pass to the vis.network when initialising/rendering it.

```
vm.nodes = new $window.vis.DataSet(nodes);
var visData = { nodes: vm.nodes, edges: vm.edges}
...
vm.network = new $window.vis.Network(container, visData, options);
...
vm.nodes.update({ label: ' ' });
```

An example of my node data is: {id: 62378, label: "Some Label", image: "https://someuri/someimage.png", brokenImage: null, x: null, …}

However I receive the following error message when attempting to update the nodes:

vis.js:7554 Uncaught Error: Option image must be defined for node type 'circularImage'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out my error, was passing in an object to nodes.update(..) instead of an array of objects. The array of objects are suppose to represent the nodes you wish to update. They require an identifier property (id) and whatever property you wish to update, in my case the label.